# how to store instance variables of a class in a file using pickle

Tags: python, class, pickle, file-handling

I wanted to create a class item to store information of different items, existing in a shop. At least following is to be
stored w.r.t. each item code, name, price, qty. Write a program to accept the data from user and store
it permanently in the file.

Here's what i did:

```
import pickle
class item:
    def __init__(self,code,name,price,qty):
        self.code=code
        self.price=price
        self.name=name
        self.qty=qty
    def store(self):
        p=open('kk.dat','wb+')
        pickle.dump(self,p)

    def show(self):
        p=open('kk.dat','rb')
        x=pickle.load(p)
        print x
        p.close()
o = item(1121,'we',340,2)
o.store()
o.show()
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: Entering self as a parameter doesn't seem to work for dump. Are there other ways to do this?

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" - *what happens*? What error you you get?

Comment: no really an error but this:

Comment: <__main__.item instance at 0x01FBA620>

Comment: And what's wrong with that? You'd get the same result if you printed `o`.

Comment: try `print(x.name)`

Comment: I guess that works